# download file java spring rest api

Tags: java, excel, spring, rest, io

i want to make a rest api controller (spring boot) that when petitioned with a get will allow me to download an excel file. currently i have this endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download.xls", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity Survey_Reports(@RequestParam(value = "evaluated") String evaluated){

    return surveyService.getSurveysFile(evaluated);

}
```

wich ultimately calls to this method:

```
public static ResponseEntity getDownloadResponse() {

    File file2Upload = new File("Survey_Reports.xls");

    Path path = Paths.get(file2Upload.getAbsolutePath());
    ByteArrayResource resource = null;
    try {
        resource = new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("there was an error getting the file bytes ", e);
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentLength(file2Upload.length())

//this line doesnt seem to work as i set the file format in the controller request mapping
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel"))
            .body(resource);
}
```

everything seems to work semi-fine as i get the download.xls(as the mapping) file correclty, but now i want to make the downloaded file have some specific name like: evaluatedName.xls or userDateEndDate.xls or some other stuff, is there a way to edit the response entity to do so? so that i dont have to name the mapping "download.xls"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In context of **HttpServletResponse response** you can do this like this

```
response.setContentType("application/csv");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + csvName);
```

and for **ResponseEntity** i assume you can use something like this:

```
 ResponseEntity.ok().header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + csvName );
```

Comment: this worked :D, this fixed the need for .xls in the mapping and let me modify the name to my convenience, thank you so much