# How to download Excel using spring rest service / spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

Excel download is not working while downloading using spring boot - issue might be setting the CONTENT TYPE , I doubt!
I have tried setting different CONTENT TYPE headers but not working with EXCEL.

## My requirement: The below code should be generic for all type of files.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/files/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> downloadAnyFile()
{

byte[] byteArray;  // data comes from external service call in byte[]

ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(byteArray, docName);
                return ResponseEntity.ok()
                        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, ATTACHMENT + docName)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                        .contentLength(resource.contentLength())
                        .body(resource);

// Also tried this below content-type but not working
String mimeType = ServletContext.getMimeType(fileName);
 .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(mimeType))

}
```

`I am seeing warning of file corrupted while opening , The downloaded excel` file should not be corrupted. It should be opened as it was before upload.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42767079/download-file-java-spring-rest-api this one is useful

Comment: @Babasheb: thanks for your reply,  # I have already tried it, but not working. #

Comment: Have you got it to work yet? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following code.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/files/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<?> downloadAnyFile() {
    String dirPath = "your-location-path";
    byte[] byteArray;  // data comes from external service call in byte[]
    try {
       String fileName = "your-custom-file-name";
      byteArray = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(dirPath + fileName));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
        .body(byteArray);
  }
```

You can use `@GetMapping` or `@PostMapping` based upon the requirments.

Comment: I have realized the problem is that, when I am uploading/sending file content of the excel file (rest of files eg:pdf, csv, .docx .zip have no issue) as byte[] byteArr = MultipartFile.getBytes() to file storage REST service input, the data is getting corrupted. I don't understand why is it so!
And I don't have any issue with the download functionality of mine. I realized it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring Boot 2.7.xx API for get the excel file

@GetMapping(value = "/ashok/excelfile", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public JsonCommonResponse downloadPatientExcelFile(HttpServletRequest request ) throws Exception {

```
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    FileDownloadResponse download = new FileDownloadResponse();
    try {
        byteArray = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/home/ashok/exel.xls")); // File Path
     //   byteArray = Base64.getEncoder().encode(byteArray);
        download.setFileContent(byteArray);
        //download.setFileType("application/octet-stream");
        download.setFileType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        download.setFileName("ashok_" + DateUtils.getFormatedCurrentDateTime() +".xlsx");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   return JsonCommonResponseHelper.getSuccessJsonResponse(download, "File", request.getServletPath());

}
```

---

public class FileDownloadResponse implements Serializable {

```
private byte[] fileContent;
private String fileType;
private String fileName;
```

}

**JsonCommonResponse** is a pojo class to set the data and send it with JSON object. modify the same as require.